# How to terminate all active logins of my account?

Tags: support, login, accounts, logout

I have logged into my account from many computers and forgot to log out sometimes. So, I do not known how many active sessions I have. How can I terminate all of them?

Comment: Raise a mod flag. Mods can clear all your sessions (on a per site basis)

Comment: @TheLostMind it's good this mods can do it though isn't is something on which the owner of the account should have the control like the OP should be able to do it for his account ? seems like i am doing a feature request :D